# Does fault-tolerance entail high availability?

Tags: high-availability, fault-tolerance

I still confuse the principle of high availability with that of fault tolerance. I have researched about the definition of each and ended up with the following answers:

- **Fault tolerance** refers to systems that have no point of failure.
- **High availability** refers to systems with minimized downtime (up to 99.999% uptime)

Additionaly, I found from the SNIA dictionary that high availability is most often achieved through failure tolerance. So, does this mean that a fault tolerance system can definitely provide high availability?

Comment: Fault tolerance is a system without a *single* point of failure, not a system without any points of failure. If any one point fails the system will still continue to operate. This is *one* technique used to provide high availability. But a fault-tolerant system does not guarantee a highly-available system because not only can a system become unavailable for a number of reasons beyond faulty points, but consider what happens when multiple points fail.

Comment: Think of it this way, a perfectly fault-tolerant system can handle single points of failure to provide high availability, but fault-tolerant systems make no guarantees about multiple points of failure.

Comment: okay, so fault tolerance just a technique to achieve the availability, but it won't prove high availability if the failure exceeds the limit of failure point, is it right?

Comment: Correct. Also consider that a system can go unavailable for reasons beyond faults, such as planned downtime or poor load balancing (which technically aren’t considered faults but rather poor design).

Comment: @trndjc *"not only can a system become unavailable for a number of reasons beyond faulty points,"* What do you mean by faulty points?

Comment: @MehdiCharife faulty points are points in a system that are prone to cause failure or unintended behaviors. In software engineering, this could be a race condition where a function is simultaneously called unexpectedly by multiple callers producing unwanted behavior. In server engineering, this could be poor allocation of virtual resources that start to break under high traffic. Fault points could be a wide assortment of things.